# Create a library or DLL in Linux and using them on Windows

Tags: windows, linux, dll

I'm a Windows developer so I'm new to the Linux environment. I was wondering if anyone had any advice or general articles that could help me build a project on Linux and compile it into a library or DLL for use in a Windows environment.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seb - what's the reason for compiling in Linux and running in Windows - can't you just compile it in Windows?

Comment: Rob - The language is C++.

Praveen - The reason is that I am trying to port an Open Source project into a DLL for use in windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [cross-compiler](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=linux%20windows%20cross%20compile), or simply install Windows and the necessary build tools inside a virtual machine (e.g. using [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning VirtualBox. I installed it and was able to build what I needed.

Comment: You should note that installing Windows in a VM environment *requires you to buy a licence from Microsoft*.

Comment: @Matthieu After the evaluation period ended, yes.