# How to compile c++ to Window's .net Dll file in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, .net, ubuntu, gcc, dll

Now I can compile successfully by using make file provided, now I want to compile the project to dll file, how should I modify the make file so that I can use the dll file in windows .net framework? What I wish to have is a .net dll (not just a win32 dll).

The make file is:

```
default: all

# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Change the path to Z3 4.1.1 accordingly
# The directory indicated by this path should contain "lib" and "bin"
# e.g. "/home/z3_src_4.1.1"
#      "/home/work/tool/z3/z3_src_4.1.1"
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
Z3_path = ../z3

JUNK = S3
SOURCE = strTheory.cpp testMain.cpp
INCLUDE = $(Z3_path)/lib
LIB = $(Z3_path)/bin/external

all: $(SOURCE)
    g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -fopenmp -static -I$(INCLUDE) -L$(LIB) $(SOURCE) -lz3 -lrt -o S3 -Wall
    @echo ""

clean:
    rm -f $(JUNK)
```

Comment: replace static with shared.

Comment: `dll` (dynamic-link library) is the name used under Windows; on linux (unix?), it's called `so` (shared object)

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to create a *shared library* in Linux, if you just search a little.

Comment: @PaoloM becasue I want to use it in windows, how should I do

Comment: Okay, then the answer is that you need to *cross compile* the code, and I don't actually know if it's possible without special tools for the generation of the DLL. You might be able to do it using something like [MinGW for Linux](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/linuxcrossmingw).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Sorry, what I want to have is a .net dll, not a win32 dll. I have modified the question to make this point clearer

Comment: @MikeKinghan not a duplicate, it is .net dll rather than win32 dll.

Comment: GCC doesn't do .NET. You might be able to cobble something together using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) though. Is there a reason you don't do it natively on Windows? It will make it *much* easier.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes, that is what in my mind. I just wondering would it gives extra advantage (e.g., less modification of code) to compile to C++ code on Ubuntu's mono rather than Window's Visual Studio?

Answer (score -1):

Search in the google for  "cross compilers on linux". This question already asked several times

[Create a library or DLL in Linux and using them on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472502/create-a-library-or-dll-in-linux-and-using-them-on-windows)

[How to compile for Windows on Linux with gcc/g++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033997/howto-compile-for-windows-on-linux-with-gcc-g)

Comment: What I wish to have is a .net dll (not just a win32 dll). Sorry, I do not give my question in a clear way, I have modified it.